# Stop gps updating after last known location is fetched

Tags: android, gps, updates, geo

I have a Location Manager:

```
private LocationManager lm;
```

I initialize it like this:

```
lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Then i need last known location which i achieve this way:

```
    if(gpsEnabled)
    {
          lastKnownLoc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }
    else if(networkEnabled)
    {
          lastKnownLoc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }
```

Now i just want the gps icon in the status bar to disappear, above all, i want it to stop checking my position.
Since i never ask for an update, nor i have a LocationListener in my code i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getLastKnownLocation()` doesn't turn on the Gps, and no ongoing process is started from that call.

As for the GPS status bar icon, it's controlled by the Android system to inform the user that his location has just been obtained, and you can't hide it.

Comment: In my project i also have a map and i called setMyLocationEnabled(true), i think this turns the gps on, am i wrong?

Comment: That is correct; the MyLocation overlay uses the GPS location service.

Comment: Ok thank you, I initially misunderstood the behavior of getLastKnownLocation.